# Return value from stored procedure is not correct

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server 2016:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
RETURN  @@ROWCOUNT
```

When I run this procedure in SSMS the return value is 43, as it should be.

I have this code snippet in my application:

```
com = New SqlCommand("MyQuery", conn)
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
prm = New SqlParameter
With prm
    .DbType = DbType.Int32
    .Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
End With
com.Parameters.Add(prm)
conn.Open()
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader
While rdr.Read
    Debug.WriteLine(rdr(0))
End While
Debug.Write(prm.Value Is Nothing)
```

The Debug statement in the While loop prints out all data in the first column so I know it is all working together but the result from the final Debug statement is True.  Why am I not getting my return value?

EDIT:
The answer is in my application code, not in the SQL.  Leaving the SQL as it is, I modified my code by changing the second line inside the prm loop to:

```
RetVal = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
```

Now, RetVal contains the return value.  Now it seems obvious that that makes sense.

Comment: You just need a rowcount of a table?

Comment: yes you only need row count or both data and row count?

Comment: If I am right, the "ReturnValue" is for stored procedures. If you are doing a normal SELECT ... then the returned values are the fields of the DataReader.

Comment: I use all the data that is returned for other purposes so, no, I need more than just the rowcount..

Comment: @muffi  Let me make two comments.  First, executing the stored query in SSMS returns the rows AND sets the return value to the row count.  Since both values are generated by SQL,, it seems to me that I ought to be able to get at them.  Especially in light of the fact that "ReturnValue" is one of the directions allowed by the Parameter.      Second, suppose that is not true.  Is there any way to get the return value (or another parameter) back from the database in addition to the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your stored procedure slightly:

```
DECLARE @RetVal int
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
SET @RetVal = @@ROWCOUNT
RETURN  @RetVal
```

If this doesn't work then try setting @RetVal using

```
SELECT @RetVal = COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because it forced me to rethink how I actually get the rowcount back.  The answer is in my edit to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Please update query as given below.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
SELECT  @@ROWCOUNT as Row_Count
```

After updating SP get the data in Dataset and in second table of Dataset you will got the value of row count.

Comment: I don't use a dataset now so I'll try Skippy's suggestion first and see what I can get.